# Why do beans have different System identityHashCode() but when I try to compare reference I get true(Im using proxy mod = target class)?

Tags: java, spring, proxy, scope

I test scopes of beans and their behavior in different situation, and I wanna test How can bean that has singleton scope and contains dependency which has prototype scope have different object of dependency.
I have two beans. First bean containt Second bean

FirstBean :

```
@Component
public class FirstBean {

    private SecondBean secondBean;

    public SecondBean getSecondBean() {
        return secondBean;
    }
    @Autowired
    public void setSecondBean(SecondBean secondBean) {
        this.secondBean = secondBean;
    }
}
```

Secondbean is dependency of First bean. It doesn't contain any logic

```
@Component
@Scope(value = "prototype",proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
public class SecondBean {

}
```

I have demo class where I use beans

```
public class DemoApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext applicationContext = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(Config.class);
        FirstBean firstBean = applicationContext.getBean(FirstBean.class);
        FirstBean firstBean1 = applicationContext.getBean(FirstBean.class);
        SecondBean secondBean = firstBean.getSecondBean();
        SecondBean secondBean1 = firstBean1.getSecondBean();
        System.out.println(secondBean);
        System.out.println(secondBean1);
        System.out.println(secondBean==secondBean1);
    }
}
```

[image]

So why they have reference on one object but their hashcode is different?

Comment: What if you print `secondBean` twice?

Comment: Because it is a proxy. The `hashCode` call is delegated to the actual underlying object instance, hence a different hashCode. Whilst the `==` is done against the actual proxy.

Comment: @M.Deinum How could they be pointing to the same proxy but delegating to separate instances?

Comment: Because it is a scoped proxy, in this case a prototype scope, which means each method call will lead to a new object being created. This creation (or managing the scope of the scoped proxy) is part of the work of a the proxy.